# Uint Variables Division result in 0 (Point Number)

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, uint256, overflow

I am trying to calculate a proportional reward by using the percentage of a wallet balance compared to a token's total supply.

```
uint256 reward = walletBalance / totalSupply * rewardPool
```

However, the result is always 0 because anything below 1 is seen as 0 in solidity (no point number support)?

Is there a 'correct' way in doing division to find percentage in this case. All above variables are uint256 and with decimal 18.

Answer (score 1):

**seems like the easy solution is by moving the rewardPool to the numerator**
so

`reward = walletBalance * rewardPool / totalSupply`

Answer (score 0):

Look into Solmate libraries to help you with this.

One exemple could be https://github.com/transmissions11/solmate/blob/main/src/utils/FixedPointMathLib.sol

Hope this helps